# Django queryset get all fields in values() plus a foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model with some fields, one of them is a FK. I would like to use

```
MyModel.objects.all().defer("pk").values()
```

and to add **a field** of my FK (myfk__name) without writing all model fields + 1 in the values.

I also would like to avoid doing another query after this one to add it manually.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think `defer("pk")` has any effect here; `values()` returns all fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `annotate`:

```
MyModel.objects.all().defer('pk').values().annotate(name=F('myfk__name'))
```